# Display variable property inside partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am returning user variable to my Partial view but i dont know how can i display that variable data inside my mvc view. Suppose i have two property on this "user" (FirstName and LastName) variable then can i access that like @user.FirstName and @user.LastName inside my view? I tried it but not works. Please advice solution for that. Thanks in advance

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _UserNav(string id)
 {
   using (BlexzWebDbEntities db = new BlexzWebDbEntities())
     {
       var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == id).FirstOrDefault();
       return PartialView("_UserNav", user);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the type of the model, for example:

```
@model User
```

Then, access like that:

```
@Model.FirstName
```

Comment: but "user" is variable not model. so how can i call @Model from view?

Comment: the `user` variable has to be some `type` so of course @Model can be used.

Comment: User user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == id).FirstOrDefault(); ok i made it as type but problem is i still cant @model User inside my view. https://ibb.co/ht3Mh6

Comment: Of course, if you have a namespace on the User class, for example `DataBase.Models.User`, you need to use that.